# What could cause a chainsaw chain to stop moving?

Tags: chainsaw

I have a 40cc Craftsman 18" chainsaw, and was cutting and the chain stopped moving.  Earlier it would rotate freely when I started it, even without pulling the trigger.  Now it does not move at all.  I'm nervous to pull it too hard, and wonder if it's just some safety setting that I accidentally triggered.  Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My saw has a brake that can protect me in case of a kickback. It sits in front of my left hand. Push forward to engage, pull back to release.

Or it could be a maintenance issue:

- Do you fill the bar oil when you fill the gas?
- Do you clean the machine after using it? Including the drive gear and the slot in the edge of the bar?
- Do you loosen the chain when putting it away? As the chain cools it contracts, and you don't want to let it get overtight. I store it loose; snug it up before using; adjust after 5-10 minutes use, when it's warm; the release when putting away.
- If you remove the bar & chain, does the drive gear spin?